# manually calculate classification report

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, statistical-significance, scikit-learn

I have a confusion matrix like as shown below

```
         pred
        0   1

     0  17  38
act     
     1  16  174
```

[image]

I am trying to find the measures of classification report manually by hand (for class 0)

When I do it for `target class = 0`, I get the 51% as value for `precision`

17/(17+16) = **51%** (Actual 0's/Actual 0's+ 1's predicted as 0's)

But in report shown below, the value is 46%. Can let me know how it is different?

[image]

Comment: What does the following script yield? 

"""
y_true = [*np.zeros(55), *np.ones(190)];
y_pred = [*np.zeros(17), *np.ones(38), *np.zeros(16), *np.ones(174)];

print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred));
print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0,1]));
"""

Comment: it yields 52%...but not sure where could be the mistake. Any way to debugthis? I mean debug my matrix

Comment: I think you need to upload your labels for us to try

Comment: my first row is for label 0, and 2nd row is for label 1

Comment: I agree with gunes, I think we need some more labels and code to figure out exactly what's going on. My intuition is that there is some simple mistake - you might be mixing up the predictions/true labels or something like that.

Comment: I updated the labels to confusion matrix. Not sure whether that is what you require